# Are angular services accessible form an async context?

Tags: angular, typescript

So, I have been trying access my services inside a promise callback.
I have added all necessary modules and imported them into my file.
I have also declared them in the constructor.

```
//This is part of my login Component Class and this line code is bound to a //button click

clicked(){
this.http.get(..)toPromise().then( this.loginCallbackHandler ).catch((error) => console.log(error));
      //any service accessed here works fine example
      console.log(this.app)// this is fine here
}
//
loginCallbackHandler(reponse){
      //accessing any service from here produces the the error below (error1)
      //For example
      console.log(this.html)
      //Or
      console.log(this.app)
}
//constructor definition
  constructor(@Host() public app: AppComponent,
              private oauthService: OAuthService,
              private http: HttpClient
              ){}

//Error1

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined
    at push../src/app/login/login.page.ts.LoginPage.loginCallbackHandler (login.page.ts:64)
    at
```

Edit:
The issue turned out to be an issue in my understanding to the context of the 'this' keyword, but not in angular services.

Comment: *Are angular services accessible form an async context?* Yes

Comment: But as I have shown above its not working out for me for some reason.

Comment: I already described why. Unbound `this` context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: just a suggestion, there's no reason to convert this to a promise. use the `.subsccribe` method of the observable and use the next / error handlers as needed

Comment: Yea, I was trying to apply my understanding to promises. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
this.http.get(..)toPromise().then( this.loginCallbackHandler )
```

to this

```
this.http.get(..)toPromise().then( this.loginCallbackHandler.bind(this) )
```

clousures has no `this` context so you must bind it.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in some comments, the `this` context is not what you expect. Either use `.bind(this)` or use the lambda syntax.

```
clicked() {
   this.http.get(..)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => this.loginCallbackHandler(response))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

I'd recommend reading up on how `this` context behaves in JavaScript (and therefore in TypeScript). [This would be a good start.](https://blog.pragmatists.com/the-many-faces-of-this-in-javascript-5f8be40df52e)

On another note, you could also use async/await if you want to use promises.

```
async clicked() {
   try {
      const response = await this.http.get(..).toPromise();
      this.loginCallbackHandler(response) ;
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank's that should be helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer to include another alternative - async await.